# How to uncheck offline mode in Intellij idea?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

My gradle in intellij idea has no cache. So i found the best solution to uncheck the offline mode in gradle. But the problem is I didn't find any in Intellij Idea 2017.1 . Please help.

Answer (score 7):

On IntelliJ 2019.2 EAP I cannot find the "Offline work" box to uncheck. However, you can go to

`$HOME/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.2/options/gradle.settings.xml`

on MacOS or the path defined by [JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and remove the `OfflineMode` option.

Comment: I had to restart IntelliJ after doing the above to get this to work. P.S. THANK YOU i would have never found this option myself.....

Answer (score 5):

If i understand you correctly,you can search `gradle' on the settings,and
[see the printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLRVQ.png)

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ2018.2.3 and somehow the 'Offline work' box in the gradle settings became checked (without my conscious intervention).

Answer (score 5):

Go to Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven
Uncheck the Work Offline option.
[image]

Comment: To find it quickly: Open the settings and search for "offline". But this solution worked fine for me. This setting had been changed without my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux user using Intellij 2019.2 you can find the Gradle option file in 
`~/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config/options/gradle.settings.xml`
or create one if it doesn't exist and add the "offlineWork" option with `value=false`

```
<application>
  <component name="GradleSystemSettings">
    <option name="offlineWork" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>
```

change the offlineWork option to false